# Solr returning different output fields for each document in result

Tags: dynamic, solr, field

Hello i've read the Solr wiki and searched here but didn't find a solution for my use-case:

We're indexing customer-data with different kind of contracts into a single document. 
So each customer will result in a Solr document witth one or more different contracts.

The fields for each contract are added dynamically via import (e.g. contract_type_1_s, contract_type_2_s, ...; contract_change_date_1_dt, contract_change_date_2_dt, ...). So all fields with '*2*' are related to contract no 2. 
With this the user is able to search for customers who have a contract of type one and none of type two and so on.

My use case is now to return only the fields of the contract which matched the query.

Here's an example:

```xml
<doc>
  <field name="id">100</field>
  <field name="customer_name">paul</field>
  <field name="contract_type_1_s">inhouse</field>
  <field name="contract_change_date_1_dt">2012-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">101</field>
  <field name="customer_name">fred</field>
  <field name="contract_type_1_s">inhouse</field>
  <field name="contract_change_date_1_dt">2012-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
  <field name="contract_type_2_s">external</field>
  <field name="contract_change_date_2_dt">2012-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">102</field>
  <field name="customer_name">karl</field>
  <field name="contract_type_1_s">external</field>
  <field name="contract_change_date_1_dt">2012-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
  <field name="contract_type_2_s">inhouse</field>
  <field name="contract_change_date_2_dt">2012-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
</doc>
```

If the user now searches for customers with contract-type 'external' the documents with ids **101** and **102** are in the result. Now i want to return different fields of the contract which matched the query.

In this example these should be **contract_change_date_1_dt** for document **102** and **contract_change_date_2_dt** for document **101**, since contract no 1 is external in document 102 and contract no 2 is external in document 101.

Is there a way to achive this behavior with build-in components?

---

I know that i can find out which fields matched the query with the highlight-component.

I endet up with following resolution, but it forces me to extend Solr:

1. Write a QParser to to identify needet fields, add them to the fl-param
2. Do a Highlighting-Query before returning the results to the Client
3. Iterate over all docs in result and add the fields which matched the query per doc into the result list

I Hope i made my problem clear. Any suggestions which is a good way to archive this are really appreciated.

greetings René

Comment: Since you know the situation with "which field matched" problem and you want to avoid extending Solr I suggest you get all fields for all documents and then parse result at client side. BTW, you'd get more responses if you used proper username and permanent account.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
the Problem is, that we'll have a lot of fields for each document if a  customer has many contracts. At the moment the maximum is about ~470. In one specific case i have to read up to 40.000 customers, that would be a huge amount of data just to throw 60% away...

Comment: Since you are merging different contracts in a single Solr document, but you need to return only contracts that match...why don't you just index each contract as a different document?

Comment: Hello javanna, thanks for the reply :-)

The users should be able to search by criteria from contract- and customer-data in one query, so we need to index all data together. 

If we index the contracts independent we loose the relation between customer and contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone needs a similar thing ;-)

I now managed to build up my custom result list in the following way:

Create a Custom QueryComponent (extending standard QueryComponent) to store the fields which are used in the query. In the prepare-method activate highlighting with the stored fields:

```java
// Making params modifieable
ModifiableSolrParams modifiableParams = new ModifiableSolrParams(params);
req.setParams(modifiableParams);
modifiableParams.set(HighlightParams.FIELDS, queryFieldList);
modifiableParams.set(HighlightParams.HIGHLIGHT, "true");
modifiableParams.set(HighlightParams.FIELD_MATCH, "true");
modifiableParams.set(HighlightParams.SIMPLE_PRE, "");
modifiableParams.set(HighlightParams.SIMPLE_POST, "");
```

Create a Custom HighlightComponent (extending standard HighlightComponent) to build the result out of the std. result. In the process-method i now get the highlight info and extract the information i need:

```java
NamedList<Object> rspValues = rb.rsp.getValues();
NamedList<Object> nlHl = (NamedList<Object>) rspValues.get("highlighting");
this.hlDocsAndFields = extractHighlightingInfo(nlHl);
```

For that i created a custom List, which is able to count the matches per contract (how much fields of contract_X_s are in the highlighted results).

This works fine.

I now stuck at the response writer who resolves the document-fields himself when he builds the response :-(

Has annyone a suggestion on changig/customizing the response writer?

greetings René

Answer (score 1):

I now managed the whole thing.

I must not change the response writer at all :-)

I just had to store all fields which i resolved for each document and add them to the response:

```
rb.rsp.setReturnFields(globalResultFields);
```

greetings René